# Background images in one class object detection

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

When training a single class object detector in Tensorflow, I am trying to pass instances of images where no signal object exists, such that the model doesn't learn that every image contains at least one instance of that class. E.g. if my signal were cats, id want to pass pictures of other animals/landscapes as background -this could also reduce false positives.

I can see that a class id is reserved in the object detection API (0) for background, but I am unsure how to code this into the TFrecords for my background images - class could be 0 but what would be the bounding box coords? Or do i need a simpler classifier on top of this model to detect if there is a signal in the image or not, prior to detecting position?

Answer (score 0):

Later approach of simple classifier, makes sense. I don't think there is a way to do the first part. You can use check on confidence score as well apart from checking the object is present.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to create a dataset with not objects of interest, for the same you need to use the same tools (like - label img) that you have used for adding the boxes, image with no BB wil have xml files with no details of BB but only details of the image. The script create tf record will create the tf record from the xml files, look at the below links for more inforamtion -

Create tf record example - 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pet_tf_record.py

Using your own dataset- 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md